# How to use Java in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I tried installing Java Language Support plugin but it was showing me an error.

> This extension is not installable on any current installed products.

An install log was also given with it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By65eR3APuDSaXdacVBwVlJ4bTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's a VS Code extension, not VS.

Comment: @SLaks I checked many videos of how to use java in Visual studio, everyone said to use this extension but it's showing me an error

Comment: That isn't a Visual Studio extension, and it cannot be used with Visual Studio.  You need https://code.visualstudio.com/.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks you solved all my problems

Comment: Are there still no VS 2017 options?

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution, not a work around of using another IDE (VScode instead of VS2017)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a VS Code extension.

You can only use it with VS Code, not Visual Studio.

https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks for the information mate! That was a Nice help